# If P = NP, then how not cannot solve NP-hardness (the one that doesn't intersect with NP-complete) in polynomial-time?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, p-vs-np

My question is that if P = NP, then we can solve any NP-hard problems (the one which is NP-complete and the one which is not-NP-complete) by saying that since we have a polynomial time algorithm to solve the NP problems and since the reduction works in polynomial time. Therefore, polynomial to polynomial is polynomial, and so we can solve any NP-hardness problem. For example, we can solve the TSP by calling to an NP-complete problem which have polynomial time since P=NP, and since the reduction is polynomial time, therefore we can solve TSP in polynomial time.

> How could disprove this argument? What is the clue to say that NP-hardness(the one which doesn't intersect with NP-complete) can not be solved in polynomial time even if P=NP.

I know that if P = NP, then we can only solve any problem in NP (but not in NP-hard). But I want to know what it makes NP-hard (the one that have no intersection with NP-complete) is not solvable in polynomial time even if P=NP since we have polynomial time reduction and polynomial time algorithm given P=NP.

Thank you

Comment: I think in the first paragraph you mean "NP-complete". The sentence " if P = NP, then we can solve any NP-hard problems" is wrong, otherwise. Maybe your actual question is "can you show me a NP-hard problem, which we already know not to belong to P?"

Comment: You're right, but I mean to use NP-hardness because I want to find a clue which fails this statement. I'm trying to find a clue where if someone give an argument as in above saying we have P=NP, and we have polynomial reduction, therefore why not having NP-hard (the one that doesn't intersect with NP-complete) to have a polynomial time

Comment: NP-hardness makes sense for the last part of the question, but not for the first, which IMO only causes confusion since you start from wrong premises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your reductions the wrong way around. A problem $X$ is **NP**-hard if every problem in **NP** can be reduced *to* $X$. That is, saying that $X$ is **NP**-hard means that, if we had an efficient algorithm for $X$, we would have an efficient algorithm for every problem in **NP**: $X$ is easy implies all of **NP** is easy.

So, suppose that **P$\,=\,$NP**. Then, all of **NP** is easy, but that tells us nothing about $X$, because the implication goes the wrong way. Maybe $X$ is easy; maybe it's hard. In fact, some **NP**-hard problems are definitely hard: the halting problem is **NP**-hard but it's undecidable, regardless of what the relationship between **P** and **NP** turns out to be.

Comment: if P=NP, then all of NP is easy, and since the reduction is also easy. Why not TSP (which is NP-hard) is also easy?! What I'm saying is TSP lies in NP-hard, then after P=NP? we claim that TSP cannot be solved in polynomial time! Why? because P=NP only solves NP problems. Now after NP=P, for example TSP we have an easy algorithm (since P=NP) and an easy reduction. So, where is the wrong?! Why not solve TSP in polynomial time after claiming that P=NP!! I know some NP-hard problems such as halting problem cannot be easy even after P=NP, but what about TSP and alike?!!

Comment: if no one has said about this, then there must be a class of problems that would contain a set of problems that are neither in NP nor in NP-complete but it is in NP-hard and if P=NP, then this class of problems will be broken to be equal to NP=P=NP-complete.

Comment: "If P = NP, then all of NP is easy" - not at all. Anything taking say $O (n^{12})$ operations is not solvable for more than moderate problem sizes. And NP hard problems are mostly problems that are _not in NP_, so P = NP says nothing at all about NP-hard problems.

Comment: @gnasher729 The conventional meaning of "easy" is "in **P**". That may not be a particularly practical definition of "easiness" but it's the one that everybody uses. I really don't understand your second sentence because my answer already explains why **P=NP** has no consequences for **NP**-hard problems that aren't **NP**-complete, and I give the halting problem as an example.

Comment: @YOUSEFY TSP is **NP**-complete so it's easy if **P=NP**. I don't understand your second comment at all.

Comment: @DavidRicherby TSP is not NP-complete, it is NP-hard problem.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Only the version of TSP which says the route less thank k for some k is an NP-complete problem. Also, the second comment means that if no one give argument about whether we have problems that lies in NP-hard problems but when we solve P=NP, then it lies in class P since we have polynomial time reduction and polynomial time algorithm for NP-complete. So, I'm assuming to make a class in NP-hard to have problems like TSP and alike.  this class name it for example NPP has the property that will be destroyed to equal to P if NP=P.

Comment: @gnasher729 NP-hard is not NP. Therefore, if P=NP, then all of NP is easy. Yes it's true statement. We don't assume that NP-hard is NP, we only consider NP, NP-complete and P that lie on NP class only. So, when you have a polynomial time algorithm for NP-complete, then P=NP=NP-complete. my question is different any way from your point.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one could potentially "disprove" that argument by proving P=NP,

since as David mentions, the halting problem is NP-hard and undecidable.

Your argument is like

> If [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach's_conjecture) is true then
>   
>   we can fit (10^(10^100))+1 items into 10^(10^100) holes
>   
>   without any hole having more than one item
>   
>   by saying that since 10^(10^100) is a sum of two primes and since the primes are odd.

:
Namely, ​ "we have a polynomial time algorithm to solve the NP problems and"

"the reduction works in polynomial time" ​ follow from your assumption,

but your attempted conclusion simply does not follow from ​ "we have a polynomial time

algorithm to solve the NP problems and" "the reduction works in polynomial time" .